# Socket error on server when initializing NHibernate

Tags: c#, sockets, asp.net-mvc-4, nhibernate

This is my first project with NHibernate and it works fine in all developer's computers here. But when I upload my application to my server (it's a shared server), sometimes (not always) when the server is initializing the application and initialize the NHibernate, I get the following error: `An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full`.
The error occurs exactly in this line `PessoaFisica user = InstitutoDaDorMVC.Helpers.LoginHelper.GetUsuarioLogado(User.Identity.Name);`, that is the line which makes NHibernate initialize in the server.

this is how I'm configuring NHibernate:

```
cfg = new Configuration()
    .SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.Dialect, "NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect")
    .SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionDriver, "NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver")
    .SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionString, ConnString)
    .SetProperty(NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionProvider, "NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider")
    .AddAssembly("InstitutoDaDorMVC");
sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
```

and then I have a method for getting the sessions:

```
    public static ISession GetSession()
    {
        ISession currentSession = null;
        currentSession = sessionFactory.OpenSession();

        return currentSession;
    }
```

I wonder if it is really my application's error or if it is a server error due to memory limitations given that it doesn't happen here in my computers and it happens on the server just sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue not related to your application, basically it happens if you try to set up TCP connections from ports that are greater than 5000 in your server.

You can setup the Maximum Number of TCP Ports that Server can allow by following steps:

1.Open `Registry Editor` - goto `run`->`regedit`
2.Goto -> `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters`
3.Goto-> `Edit` menu, click `New`, and then add the following registry entry:

```
Value Name: MaxUserPort
Value Type: DWORD
Value data: 65534
```

now restart the Server and try to run your Application.

See this link for more info : [An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2009/03/09/understanding-the-error-an-operation-on-a-socket-could-not-be-performed-because-the-system-lacked-sufficient-buffer-space-or-because-a-queue-was-full.aspx)